# Genetic algorithm to throw ball at a target

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, physics-engine, pymunk

I would like to use Pymunk to produce a genetic algorithm in which the aim is to throw a ball at a target.

I know how to do most of the genetic algorithm stuff, but Pymunk is new to me. The idea is that the ball will start from a fixed position, say 1.5m above the ground and 20m horizontally away from the hoop. Say the ball weighs 1kg. Then, the ball will be launched with a certain amount of force at a certain angle. The fitness will be the closest it came to the center of the target during its flight.

So, for example, an individual in the population may look like `[10.0, 5.0]` where 10.0 means 10N applied horizontally and 5.0 means 5N applied vertically.

I don't want it to run every simulation in a window I can see, but I would like to be able to turn that on so I can run it for the fittest individual after a certain number of generations or once it reaches a certain fitness level. Here is a visual representation of what I mean https://prnt.sc/pn1hoc.

I've tried my best to work it out myself using the pymunk documentation, but I haven't found it to be very helpful and so I am rather stuck.

What I know is that I need to initiate a space

```
space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = (0.0, -900.0)  # not sure what this means?
```

Then create a ball in that space

```
def add_ball(space):
    mass = 1
    radius = 14
    moment = pymunk.moment_for_circle(mass, 0, radius)
    body = pymunk.Body(mass, moment)
    body.position = 100, 150
    shape = pymunk.Circle(body, radius)
    space.add(body, shape)
    return shape
```

Although this ball will start falling, not sure how to make it start statically.

Then to generate the target I should do something like

```
def add_target(space):
    body = pymunk.Body(body_type = pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    body.position = (500, 300)
    target = pymunk.Segment(body, (-150, 0), (-150, 50), 5)
    space.add(target)
    return target
```

I would really appreciate some help with piecing this together with such that I can run the simulations from within my genetic algorithm, but also toggle them to run in a window.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have worked out how to put in the floor, here is all of my code so far

```
import sys, random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import pymunk
import pymunk.pygame_util


def add_ball(space):
    mass = 1
    radius = 14
    moment = pymunk.moment_for_circle(mass, 0, radius)
    body = pymunk.Body(mass, moment)
    body.position = (50, 150)
    shape = pymunk.Circle(body, radius)
    space.add(body, shape)
    return shape


def add_floor(space):
    body = pymunk.Body(body_type = pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    body.position = (0, 0)
    target = pymunk.Segment(body, (0, 5), (600, 5), 5)
    space.add(target)
    return target


def add_target(space):
    body = pymunk.Body(body_type = pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    body.position = (700, 300)
    target = pymunk.Segment(body, (-150, 0), (-150, 50), 5)
    space.add(target)
    return target


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    space = pymunk.Space()
    space.gravity = (0.0, -900.0)

    target = add_target(space)
    floor = add_floor(space)
    balls = []
    draw_options = pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions(screen)

    ball_count = 0
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                sys.exit(0)
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit(0)

        if ball_count < 1:
            ball_shape = add_ball(space)
            balls.append(ball_shape)
            ball_count += 1

        space.step(1/50.0)

        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        space.debug_draw(draw_options)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(50)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Isn't the third variable in your genome (the angle) redundant? You've already split your force vector in a x component and a y component

Comment: And an initial force doesn't seem like a good way to model shooting a ball. Maybe you can try an initial velocity in the x direction and an initial velocity in the y direction as your genome?

Comment: @MauritsvanAltvorst Yes you're correct

Comment: @MauritsvanAltvorst Why not?

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to this question I think. My number one advice is to start with the smallest thing possible and then expand from there. This works very well for all sorts of problems when there are several parts that are confusing or you dont know how to solve.

Here are some pointers:

**You need to figure out exactly how you want to measure fitness.** Some examples:

1. Measure the ball's distance to target after a certain time. This should be very easy to implement since you just need to measure distance once, when simulation reach end. However, it might be difficult to decide what the time should be.
2. Measure the ball's minimum distance to target during one "throw". I guess this is better than 1, but depends on what you want to train for. In this case you could measure the distance each time you call the step function, and keep track of its minimum value. I think I would start with this method of measuring the fitness since its fairly easy but still feels ok.

**You probably want to separate the simulation from its display.** So you should try to write up function that does one round/"throw" and simulate it to its end.

For example, here is a quick example I put together with a method do_one_throw that takes impulse of throw as input and return the minimum distance to target withing 1000 simulation steps:

```
def add_ball(space):
    mass = 1
    radius = 14
    moment = pymunk.moment_for_circle(mass, 0, radius)
    body = pymunk.Body(mass, moment)
    body.position = (50, 150)
    shape = pymunk.Circle(body, radius)
    space.add(body, shape)
    return shape


def add_floor(space):
    body = pymunk.Body(body_type = pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    body.position = (0, 0)
    target = pymunk.Segment(body, (0, 5), (600, 5), 5)
    space.add(target)
    return target


def add_target(space):
    body = pymunk.Body(body_type = pymunk.Body.STATIC)
    body.position = (700, 300)
    target = pymunk.Segment(body, (-150, 0), (-150, 50), 5)
    space.add(target)
    return target

def do_one_throw(impulse):
    space = pymunk.Space()
    space.gravity = (0.0, -900.0)

    ball_shape = add_ball(space)
    add_floor(space)
    target_shape = add_target(space)

    ball_shape.body.apply_impulse_at_local_point(impulse)

    min_distance_to_target = 1000000
    steps = 1000
    for _ in range(steps):
        space.step(1/50.0)
        distance_to_target = target_shape.body.position.get_distance(ball_shape.body.position)
        if distance_to_target < min_distance_to_target:
            min_distance_to_target = distance_to_target
    return min_distance_to_target
```

**Once you have these basics inplace you can add more fancy features**

- For example, you can start easy by just using prints to print out what is happening in the simulation to start with.
- The gravity you set on the space is the gravity vector. Note that pymunk is unit independent, so as long as all the things you pass in are consistent it should work out right: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/overview.html#mass-weight-and-units
- You can optimize my quick and dirty code above, for example by having some smarter logic to decide when to end the simulation so you dont need to run all 1000 steps if the ball is already way out with no chance of coming back.
- You can add pygame drawing code, looks like you already have come a long way here
- Improve measuring of distance to target, now I made the easiest solution by measuring the distance between the bodies, but you probably want the distance between the shapes, so that if shapes collide the distance is 0.